# Twisted, deferred requests and File vs ErrorPage

Tags: python, twisted, deferred

I'm currently building a http server with python/twisted.

This server must fetch content on another web server, store it locally and send the response back to the client. If it encounters a 404, it must try to serve the local file, or will fail if there's no local file at all.

To achieve this, I'm using differed requests. My code roughly looks like this:

```
class RemoteFile(Resource):
    isLeaf = True

    def render_GET(self, request):
        # Start downloading the corresponding file on the remote server
        # Will call `self.serve_local_file` when done
        return NOT_DONE_YET

    def serve_local_file(self, request):
        if self.file_exists_for_request(request):
            fileResource = File(filename)
            fileResource.render(request)
        else:
            page = NoResource("No such file")
            html = page.render(request)

            # The next two lines are my problem
            request.write(html)
            request.finish()
```

I had to add the last two lines (`write()` and `finish()`) in order to get the request to actually finish. I don't need these lines for a `File` resource, because it handles the write/finish by itself, unlike the NoResource.

This is not a problem per se, but it turns out that this `page` variable is not hardcoded, and it's actually a `fallback` attribute on my class, which is supposed to be a `Resource`. It means that I could, in the future, want to replace it with a default `File`. In which case I'll have to modify my code...

Am I doing something wrong, or is this an inconsistency in the interfaces of `File` and `ErrorPage` ?

Comment: Please include a complete, runnable example so we can actually run something and see what the behavior is, rather than guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a hint in your question itself:

```
return NOT_DONE_YET
```

This is part of how an `IResource` signals whether it is returning a string which the caller must write to the request before explicitly "finishing" the request or whether the `IResource` is taking responsibility for doing those things.

Check the return value of whatever you're calling `render` on and then act accordingly.